# Copying all branches from repo1 to repo2 in Git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am trying to copy all branches from `repo1` to `repo2`

I have executed the following commands but I still don't see branches in repo2

```
cd repo2
git checkout master
git remote add r1remote **url-of-repo1**
git fetch r1remote
git merge r1remote/master --allow-unrelated-histories
git remote rm r1remote
```

Do I need to perform `git push` in some certain way?

Answer (score 1):

```
git push REMOTE '*:*'
git push REMOTE --all
```